# pandas: merge dataframe and series / fill missing datapoints

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge `pd.DataFrame` and `pd.Series` including all the missing data.

```
print(x)

>>> movie  rating  user
0    100       1     1
1    200       4     1
2    300       3     1
3    100       5     2
4    200       3     2
5    300       2     3
```

`x` is `pd.DataFrame`.

```
print(y)

>>> 0    100
1    200
2    300
3    400
```

`y` is `pd.Series`.
I want to use this data as `movie` column in `x`.
With `x` and `y`, I want to have a result like:

```
    movie  rating  user
0     100     1.0     1
1     200     4.0     1
2     300     3.0     1
3     400     NaN     1
4     100     5.0     2
5     200     3.0     2
6     300     NaN     2
7     400     NaN     2
8     100     NaN     3
9     200     NaN     3
10    300     2.0     3
11    400     NaN     3
```

The combined data should be basically `x` with column `movie=[100,200,300,400]` like in `y` for each user.

Comment: Please explain how you want to combine the two objects. It is not clear from your example.

Comment: @DYZ It seems the series `[100, 200, 300]` is meant to be a repetitive one, and this has to be replaces by a different repetitive series `[100, 200, 300, 400]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unstack` + `stack` + `reindex`

```
x.set_index(['user','movie']).rating.unstack().\
     reindex(columns=y).\
        stack(dropna=False).\
           reset_index(name='rating')
Out[40]: 
    user  movie  rating
0      1    100     1.0
1      1    200     4.0
2      1    300     3.0
3      1    400     NaN
4      2    100     5.0
5      2    200     3.0
6      2    300     NaN
7      2    400     NaN
8      3    100     NaN
9      3    200     NaN
10     3    300     2.0
11     3    400     NaN
```

Comment: Awesome solution; I end up with columns called `['user', 'level_1', 'rating']` on pandas 0.23.4 though.

Comment: @fuglede I think the version different may cause the out put slightly different .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby`, and `reindex`, to reindex each ID on `y.values`. Then you can reset the index, and `ffill` and `bfill` the `user` column by each group to fill the `NaN` values:

```
new = (x.groupby('user',as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda i: i.set_index('movie').reindex(y.values))
       .reset_index('movie'))

new['user'] = new.groupby(new.index)['user'].ffill().bfill().astype(int)

>>> new
   movie  rating  user
0    100     1.0     1
0    200     4.0     1
0    300     3.0     1
0    400     NaN     1
1    100     5.0     2
1    200     3.0     2
1    300     NaN     2
1    400     NaN     2
2    100     NaN     3
2    200     NaN     3
2    300     2.0     3
2    400     NaN     3
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally much prefer @Wen's solution, but let's just note as an alternative that you could create desired `user` and `movie` columns, then merge that with the original `DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(set(x.user), y)), columns=['user', 'movie'])\
  .merge(x, how='outer')

Out[76]:
    user  movie  rating
0      1    100     1.0
1      1    200     4.0
2      1    300     3.0
3      1    400     NaN
4      2    100     5.0
5      2    200     3.0
6      2    300     NaN
7      2    400     NaN
8      3    100     NaN
9      3    200     NaN
10     3    300     2.0
11     3    400     NaN
```